# WinPhone8 Camera API seems to keep running after dispose call

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, camera, windows-phone-8

I am facing a severe issue with the [Camera API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202956%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), and even if I know that in 99.99% of the situations, frameworks are not to blame, I'm starting to consider that there may be an issue with the way cameras are handled in windows phone.

## The Issue

My code is trivial, there are just two very simple pages: the first one is a button used to navigate to the second one, which uses the camera API and renders the preview buffer on screen. On the first page, I also added a rectangle with a looping animation to rotate it, in order to force the application to update the frame rate.

The result of a profile session is as follows:

[image: Test application lifecycle]

As long as I stay on the first page, the framerate counter displays a rock solid 60fps. Once I launch the second page featuring the camera, the fps drops due to the use of the system camera. However, when I hit the back key, the camera is correctly disposed, but the framerate is a bit lower (~53 fps). **More impressive, the graph data shows that something is still running and hurting the perfs!** The built-in analysis tells me that system apps use 47% of the CPU, the same that when the camera page was shown!

Is there a known reason for this behavior?

## My Code

My code-behind for the second page:

```
public partial class MyScannerView : PhoneApplicationPage {
    private PhotoCamera camera;

    public MyScannerView() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e) {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        camera = new PhotoCamera(CameraType.Primary);
        viewfinderBrush.SetSource(camera);
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e) {
        base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);

        if (camera != null) {
            camera.Dispose();
            camera = null;
        }
    }
}
```

My XAML for the second page:

```
<Canvas x:Name="viewfinderCanvas">
    <Canvas.Background>
        <VideoBrush x:Name="viewfinderBrush">
            <VideoBrush.RelativeTransform>
                <CompositeTransform x:Name="viewfinderTransform" CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" />
            </VideoBrush.RelativeTransform>
        </VideoBrush>
    </Canvas.Background>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: Do you know you can get more details about what exactly is running? If you dig deeper into the Performance Analyzer, you can see which function call takes certain percentage of the CPU time. Maybe it will help you identify what's running.

Comment: Indeed. However, the UI thread takes only 4.6% of the CPU, which is not surprising since the code is really basic. Some frames takes a lot of time to be drawn, but all I can tell is that "System.Windows.dll:ManagedFunction_0(...)" seems to be the culprit. Something is running in the background, but that's all I can say.

Comment: BTW, is there some kind of official bug tracker for WinPhone

Answer (score 1):

I had similar looking issue with application, which uses camera.
Managed to overcome it with using not OnNavigatedFrom but OnNavigatingFrom override and doing it in such order:

1. Unsubscribing from events
2. Dispose();
3. camera = null;

Comment: Thanks, I'll test that as soon as possible and will tell you!